# Continue message where strpos left off

Tags: php

I have spent hours trying to find a solution for this but I cannot.

I have a text field that I am using `strpos` to break up on the first space after 3000 characters:

```
 $pos=strpos($message2, ' ', 3000);
 $pos2=substr($message2,0,$pos );
 echo $pos2;
```

Then I am using `substr` to continue the message from 3000 characters:

```
 $pos4=substr($message2,3000);
 echo $pos4;
```

The issue I am having is that the message will not continue from where the previous match finished.

Example, if my message was "and this is the end, hello world" `$pos2` finished at "and this the end" `$pos4` continues at "nd, hello world".

How do I make it so `$pos2` returns "and this is the end" and `$pos4` return ", hello world"?

Comment: You could split them into arrays of 3000 characters

Comment: @Avi that is a bad solution. And it means you need to find the space in an array instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to be a bit clearer. It's possible you might understand the code better now and find a solution yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code.

```
$max_len=10;
$message2="12345 789 abcde ghij lmnop";

//if you want to break at the first whole word before $max_len characters
$pos1=strrpos(substr($message2, 0, $max_len), ' ');
echo substr($message2,0,$pos1) ."<br>";
echo substr($message2,$pos1+1)  ."<br>";

//if you want to break at the first whole word after $max_len characters
$pos2=strpos($message2,' ',$max_len);
echo substr($message2,0,$pos2) ."<br>";
echo substr($message2,$pos2+1)  ."<br>";
```

Comment: thank you so much, learnt something completely new here :) this will help greatly and I really appreciate it

Comment: Isn't it *last whole word **after** 3000 characters*? The offset is 3000, so it skips 3000 characters then finds the space? If you used strrpos then yes it would be before.

Comment: With strpos it's after for sure. But I have no clue what strrpos returns. https://3v4l.org/UJkep , 17 is `e` in `end`

Comment: @Andreas, strrpos returns the last occurrence of the string, in this case a space. You can think of the extra 'r' as reverse.

Comment: @WNP yes but with offset the same as with strpos then it should return then space prior to the offset. Right? Did you even look at the link?

Comment: @Andreas yes I looked at the link. Both strpos and strrpos only use what is beyond the offset, not taking into consideration what is before.

Comment: I changed the code to give you better examples.  You can plug in your own test string.